# How to specify last occurrancy of "syn match <Name> <Pattern>" command in Vim

Tags: syntax, vim

I want to write a syntax file for VIM, my problem is:

In order to highlight last occurrence of some pattern in syntax file, 
how to define the _last occurrence in the command below?

`sync match <Name> +<Pattern String>+`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `.*\zs` to the front of the pattern would match the last occurrence of the pattern on the line or `\_.*\zs` for the last occurrence of pattern in the file.

(However I have no idea if this is a good idea)

Comment: Firstly Thank you for your answer. However, This only match last occurrence in One Row. Not the last occurrence of overall text.

Comment: @Victor that isn't at all obvious from the question. I assumed you meant line since you didn't specify. See edit for whole files.